# How to delay the shadow

Tags: jquery, delay, shadow

In short. There is one button on a page. Once the button is clicked, a list of links slides down from a neg. y position. Once the list has reached the end of its rope and is hanging, i would like to have a shadow fade in for the li elements. Any suggestions? I tried using javscript to get the element, add a class to it, and put a delay on the class, but it was in vain. Please help.

```
<div>
<ul class='list-group' id='list' style='position:absolute; top:-380px;'>
<h1 id='linkHeader'>Links</h1>
<li class = 'list-group-item shadow'><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li class = 'list-group-item shadow'><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li class = 'list-group-item shadow'><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li class = 'list-group-item shadow'><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<button id = 'openLinkListButton' onclick='ani()'>click me</button>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/aGEeeG)

Comment: You need that also the text from the li elements has a fade?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you could do `$('.class').addClass('.classname').delay(ms)`

`.delay()` is used in milliseconds, and delays the function after it. So if you wanted to have something fade in, but have a delay, then it would be

`$('.class').delay(time).fadeIn(time);`, where 'time' is in milliseconds.

`.delay()` just delays the function that happens after it.